# How can I compress four floats into a string?

Tags: python, encoding, compression

I would like to represent four floats e.g, `123.545, 56.234, -4534.234, 544.64` using the set of characters [a..z, A..Z, 0..9] in the shortest way possible so I can encode the four floats and store them in a filename. What is the most efficient to do this?

I've looked at base64 encoding which doesn't actually compress the result. I also looked at a polyline encoding algorithm which uses characters like `)` and `{` and I can't have that.

Comment: Efficient by what metric? Easiest filename to read? Shortest code to write?

Comment: @robᵩ Shortest string

Comment: It is impossible. because sum([a-zA-Z0-9]) is 62.
and if we make float array as bit array like huffman algorithm, then we must replace splitted bit array as a-zA-Z0-9. but we have only 62 characters.

you have to remove some character to align 32 characters, or add(for base 64, added character is '+' and '/') two characters to 1:1 match for bit array.

I think huffman coding + urlsafe base64 encoding(It is replace '+', '/' as '-', '_') is best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `struct` module to store them as binary 32-bit floats, and encode the result into base64. In Python 2:

```
>>> import struct, base64
>>> base64.urlsafe_b64encode(struct.pack("ffff", 123.545,56.234,-4534.234,544.64))
'Chf3Qp7vYELfsY3F9igIRA=='
```

The == padding can be removed and re-added for decoding such that the length of the base64 string is a multiple of 4. You will also want to use URL-safe base64 to avoid the / character.